Multiple Programs Same Source, Getting Program Icons Correct
I am using C++ VS 2010.  The source is used for a number of different products.  The compiler is set up to build multiple configurations, one for each of the EXEs.  Each configuration has a different preprocessor directive for the EXE to be produced. I'm trying to get the resource file set up correctly to set the correct program icon for each EXE.  I have the following set in the .rc2 file included in the .rc file
#ifdef CFGA
IDI_ICON ICON IconA.ico

#elif defined(CFGB)
IDI_ICON ICON IconB.ico

#elif defined(CFGC)
IDI_ICON ICON IconC.ico

#elif defined(CFGD)
IDI_ICON ICON IconD.ico

#elif defined(CFGE)
IDI_ICON ICON IconE.ico

#else
IDI_ICON ICON IconA.ico
#endif

When I load the resources in the project, an icon called IDI_ICON appears, but only IconA, regardless of the configuration selected.  When I compile things get very weird:
CFGA - Gets IconC
CFGB - Gets IconA
CFGC - Gets IconA
CFGD - Gets IconC
CFGE - Gets the default Windows EXE icon
I have searched the entire project for references to the icons and there is nothing odd I can see.  The DSP file has a section defining the source files.  It was only defining IconA, but I manually added the other icons with no change in behavior.  The vcxproj.filters file also only named IconA, but I added the rest with no change.  I even tried changing the order in the file, but no change.
The .rc file has no icons defined at all.
When I commented out everything except the definition for IconC in the rc2 file, then closed and reloaded the project.  The icon that shows up in the resource view is the correct icon, however when I compile, the icon assigned to the EXE is IconA.
This has been driving me nuts for two days and I haven't found where anybody else has ever run into this.  Any solution to this mess?

If RC files allow #pragmas, put a #pragma message("I am building CFGA") and similar messages to confirm exactly what the compiler is seeing when it builds your application.  Then look at the Build Output to see if the message you see there makes sense.  As a matter of fact, you should always put #pragma message to ensure you are building the configuration you suspect is being built.  This way there aren't any surprises.  If RC files do not allow pragmas, then you should stick somewhere in your C++ header fille(s) the #pragma message.

I seem to remember the rc files have separate preprocessor settings? Maybe you've set different defines for the RC files to the rest of your code?

The way the programs are used, each one has specific data that is tied to the EXE.  Some of the data is encrypted and the key is in the EXE unlocked by the program you're building.  If the compiler compiled the wrong EXE, it's going to be obvious very quickly.
There is a Resources section in the Properties, but it imports all the Prepossessor Definitions from the C/C++ section.  I experimented in the Resources section with the same results.

I think this may be something with the OS.  I tested on another computer.  When I copied the EXE over to the other computer, it showed up with the right icon.  Somehow it looks like Windows is doing something screwy.
